# how to handle in_app_purchase flutter auto renewed subscriptions

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store, auto-renewable

I am missing documentation for in_app_purchase behaviour such as:

1. What happens if subscription is auto-renewed a) do I have to restore via PurchaseStatus.restored or new purchases will arrive via PurchaseStatus.purchased
2. If new purchases will arrive via PurchaseStatus.restored on subscription renewal but app is turned off? Will it be triggered upon turning app on?
3. Should I run validate expiration date of all existing subscriptions on every app start?

Comment: How did you solve it? I was wondering how to handle renew, cancel or expiration of subscription. Because I found out, that if you call restorePurchases, it returns the purchaseDetails only when the subscription is valid. When the subscription is invalid there is no incoming value from the stream. But in my csse it is a bit difficult to make decision where I should do the check or how long I should wait to decide that subscription is invalid. it;s quite weird.

Comment: I abandoned this package because it is buggy. I mean i have implemented everything but flutter has not solving 2 bugs related to it and without them solved whole flow cannot be implmented. I switched to RevenuCat. Have headache free solution now.

Comment: thanks for info, Ok I'll take look at the revenueCat ;)

Comment: Yes it is a very frustrating package to work with. Spend lots of time to debug. I did not want a 3rd party handling this and was suspect of all the comments pointing to revenuecat but I am afraid we will go too.